# What can this curved brick with square holes be used for?

Tags: part-identification, piece-usage, activity-support

I recently came across this piece:

[image: 73878]

What piece is it, and how can it be used?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The part is [Window Round 3 x 3 x 2 (73878)](https://rebrickable.com/parts/73878/window-round-3-x-3-x-2/).

[image: 73878]

It was a new mold for 2021, and one of its first uses was as windows on [Andrea's House (41449)](https://rebrickable.com/sets/41449-1/andreas-family-house).

[image: Andrea's House]

This piece can be used on buildings anywhere you'd like a curved window. It is easy to imagine how it could have been used on earlier sets, such as the "curved" windows on the Pet Shop:

[image: 10218 Pet Shop]

This part introduces opportunities for curved windows, but it continues to use existing window glass. It uses the [1x2x2 glass (60601)](https://rebrickable.com/parts/60601/glass-for-window-1-x-2-x-2-flat/):

[image: 60601]

This means that the part is also compatible with other window panes, such as the [1x2x2 bars](https://rebrickable.com/parts/38320/bars-for-window-1-x-2-x-2/):

[image: 38320]

These parts are paired together to create the curved window seen in [Chamber of Secrets (76389)](https://rebrickable.com/sets/76389-1/hogwarts-chamber-of-secrets/):

[image: 76389 Tower Window]

Like most parts, there's plenty of ways to use it. It shows up as fences in [Heartlake City Park (41447)](https://rebrickable.com/sets/41447-1/heartlake-city-park/):

[image: https://rebrickable.com/sets/76389-1/hogwarts-chamber-of-secrets/]

It even gets used to create a water wheel in [Medieval Castle (31120)](https://rebrickable.com/sets/31120-1/medieval-castle/):

[image: 31120 water wheel]

I played around a little with this part at microscale and put together a Mars research station based around the idea of round pods:

[image: Mars Research Station]

[image: Mars Research Station top]

Comment: The curved window brick would not have been a good choice for the pet shop: half-hexagonal bay windows were a common feature of the architecture of that period; curved ones were unheard-of.